# c# How to send HTTP command as this - http://192.168.10.1/api/control?alert=101002

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have this [hardware](http://www.patlite.com/product/detail0000000224.html) from Patlite,
This hardware has an HTTP command control function, for example, if I copy the url "http://192.168.10.1/api/control?alert=101002" to chrome in my computer, it will activate the hardware as needed.

**I want to send the command from my code.**

I tried this code with no luck:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://10.0.22.222/api/control");
        request.Method = "post";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postData = "alert=101002";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

There is a picture from the manual:[image]

Thanks

Comment: "I tried this code with no luck" What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string Get(string url, Encoding encoding)
        {
            try
            {
                var wc = new WebClient { Encoding = encoding };
                var readStream = wc.OpenRead(url);
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(readStream, encoding))
                {
                    var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //throw e;
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
```

like this code use the url "http://192.168.10.1/api/control?alert=101002" to send get request.Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, so i just needed to open it as a WebClient as Chrome?

Comment: @Eran.G  Yes,The effect is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a webrequest instance for this.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.10.1/api/control?alert=101002");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

You may need to set some properties as request method and credentials for this to work.

See this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: When you answer me, I was just editing the answer to add what i have tried.

Comment: @Eran.G But you don't say nothing of the errors you had with your code. What happened?

Comment: As you can see, W.Ym helped me because it was clear enough, please remove the -1 from my question.